# How do I write an extract method [

Tags: r, data-extraction

```
obj <- read.fe_data("../data/grammatical_facial_expression", "b", "emphasis")
```

the structure of obj is 1344 observations of 4 variables. Using the extract method [ I need to write, I should get 3 obs of 4 variables after running this line.

```
sub_gfe_obj <- gfe_obj[1:3]
```

What does it mean to write an extract method [? How do I proceed? Writing an extract method doesn't mean for me to write a function right?

How do I make sure that I handle recycling, logical indexing and negative indexing in the function/

Thank you.

Comment: I think your homework problem is designed to make you determine what class the result of that specialized read function might be and then to write a method for that particular class. Hopefully the result is an S4 object so you can use the greater flexibility.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm afraid I don't understand. The class of the obj is a made up one called "gfe"